# Can you share a .swift file between an app and its extension if it relies on app-only code

Tags: ios, swift, ios-targets

I have the following set of files in my project:

[image: Filestructurepic]

The IAPHelper class uses the objective-c through a bridging header. I was wondering if I could use the IAPHelper class in both my app and its app extension like this:

(Setting IAPHelper's target membership)

[image: IAPHelper_Membership]

Without making KeychainWrapper being a member of both classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not seem to work.

I made `TestClassOne`

```
import Foundation

class TestClassOne {
static internal func addOneOne() -> Int {
    return 2;
}


}
```

`TestClassOne` is only part of one target.

I made `TestClassTwo`

```
import Foundation

class TestClassTwo {
internal static func callTestClassOne() -> Int {

    let i = TestClassOne.addOneOne()
    return i


}

}
```

`TestClassTwo` belonged too both targets. I would keep on getting the error `TestClassOne` not recognized when the `TestClassOne` file was set to only one target but once I set the `TestClassOne` file to both targets that error stopped appearing.